# GL_INVALID_OPERATION in glGenerateMipmap(incomplete cube map)

Tags: opengl, textures, cubemap, mipmaps

I'm trying to learn OpenGL and i'm using SOIL to load images.

I have the following piece of code:

```
GLuint texID = 0;

bool loadCubeMap(const char * baseFileName) {

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);

    glGenTextures(1, &texID);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, texID);

    const char * suffixes[] = { "posx", "negx", "posy", "negy", "posz", "negz" };
    GLuint targets[] = {
        GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X, GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_X,
        GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Y, GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Y,
        GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Z, GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Z
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        int width, height;
        std::string fileName = std::string(baseFileName) + "_" + suffixes[i] + ".png";
        std::cout << "Loading: " << fileName << std::endl;        
        unsigned char * image = SOIL_load_image(fileName.c_str(), &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGB);
        if (!image) {
            std::cerr << __FUNCTION__ << " cannot load image " << fileName << " (" << SOIL_last_result() << ")" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
        SOIL_free_image_data(image);
    }

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, 0);
    return true;

}
```

When i call this, the images load successfully, but then i get an error in console:

```
---- OGL DEBUG ----
message <1>: 'API' reported 'Error' with 'High' severity: 
GL_INVALID_OPERATION in glGenerateMipmap(incomplete cube map)
---- BACKTRACE ----
```

and no cubemap is displaying at all.
Do you see any mistake in this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your line of:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
```

You should have the GL_TEXTURE_2D replaced with your variable **"targets[]"** so that as you iterate through your for loop you specify GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X, etc.

The changed line would be:

```
glTexImage2D(targets[i], 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
```

Even though you are technically creating a 2D texture, OpenGL needs to know what part of the cubemap the incoming texture needs to become.